# error in multiple task assignment

Tags: apex

i have crate a multiple assignment task for same opportunity with different users. i have write this code for task creation

```
public PageReference saveTask(){
    if(IdTask.size()>0){
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();            
        for(String str : IdTask){
            newTask.OwnerId=str;
            taskList.add(newTask);
        }
        try{
            insert taskList;
        }catch(DMLException e){

        }
        PageReference parentPage = new PageReference('/' + WhatId);
        parentPage.setRedirect(true);
        return parentPage;
    }
    return null;        
}
```

but getting a error. but owner id different.

> System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two
>   identically equal elements

Visualforce:

```
<apex:PageBlockSection title="Task Information">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Assigned To</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputLabel style="border-left-color: #c00;">
                    <apex:outputLabel >{!assignedToLable}<br/></apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;">{!assignedToTaskSize}</apex:outputLabel>
                </apex:outputLabel>                    
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Related To</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!newTask.WhatId}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Subject</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!newTask.Subject}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Name</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!newTask.WhoId}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Type</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!newTask.Type}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Due Date</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!newTask.ActivityDate}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >Comments</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!newTask.Description}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:PageBlockSection>
```

pls help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a single `Task` object multiple times to your list. Instead you need to create a new `Task` object each time:

```
for (Id id : IdTask) {
     Task t = new Task(OwnerId = id, ...);
     taskList.add(t);
}
```

You will also need to set other `Task` fields i.e. replace the `...` with other assignments. Or you can clone a base `Task`.

Comment: Hi @Keith Thanks for reply. i have create task object which are reference to Vf page. similar to the Standard task page. i want to change only Owner id rest of the information are same.

Comment: @GmDeepakChounan21 Still unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do. Suggest you edit your question to describe that in more detail.

Comment: @GmDeepakChounan21 You still need to create new `Task` instances. Right now, you're adding the same `Task` instance to the list over and over. Because it's the same instance, **when you go to change the owner id, you actually end up modifying the owner id of the records already in the list**. Thus, you get your error about inserting identical items in the list. You can verify this by putting your list in a debug statement (and then inspecting the log).

Comment: Hi @Ketih It's work fine ... :)